# How to show the overflow:hidden content using jQuery / JS when a user clicks on an image?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am building a feed reader and on my first page I show a lot of post previews. A user has the option to click on the title and visit the source link.

In addition I would like to give them the option to click on a small icon, like a plus sign `+` to view the rest of the post preview in my page.

As you can see on http://jsfiddle.net/BLUzJ/ I have set a `max-height` and `overflow:hidden` if the content of post preview is more than this. 95% of the post previews have a lot of text hidden.

For now the max-height is set to 10.3em as below

```
#text {
    max-height:10.3em;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

When an icon in the post (I guess there will be in a corner of the post preview) is clicked, the max-height changes to allow user to read the rest.

My application is written in PHP, and I get the title, image, content from RSS feeds.
I think that this is a jQuery, JavaScript solution but I do not know how to do it.

Thank you for your ideas and examples.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using jquery, since you added that tag: http://jsfiddle.net/r4F8Q/3/

- added an element with class `.toggle`, which could be your icon
- added css rule for `#text.expanded` which removed `max-height`
- jquery adds/removes class `expanded` from element `#text`

Comment: That looks great! As you may noticed I will have many `<div id="post">...</div>` How does this affect the fact that I use #text ?

Comment: Ah, you should be using classes then.  There should be only one of any #id per page.  But as for the jquery chain... `.closest()` will give you the nearest matching ancestor (http://api.jquery.com/closest/), so it will only grab the the `#text` that is the parent of `.toggle` -- none of the others.

Comment: ...to clarify... the parent of the `.toggle` that was clicked.

Comment: stupid jsfiddle sucked me in. more detail: http://jsfiddle.net/katylava/cqg6p/12/ -- just for funsies.

Answer (score 0):

To show all of the content of the post, you can set the `max-height` of the element whose icon has been clicked to auto.  Once you get a hold of the element that you wish to expand (either by using `document.getElementById("id")` or by traversing the DOM), you can set this property by doing the following:

```
x.style.maxHeight = "none";
```

You can set this as the `onclick` event for the expand icon, if you wish.  Do note that this will not animate the expansion; for that you should probably use something like jQuery.

EDIT: Updated the jsFiddle with a simple example, which expands when the title is clicked. http://jsfiddle.net/BLUzJ/6/

Answer (score 0):

Here is a starting fiddle. It expands on clicking the text. You would obviously have to do some more work to have a trigger that expands/collapses the section.

http://jsfiddle.net/BLUzJ/10/